# Как получить указатель на временный файл, чтобы использовать функцию fputcsv()?

Tags: php

Написал класс, для создания временного файла. Хочу в него положить `csv`, но не получается.

```
class TmpFile {

private $tmpFile;

public function __construct () {

    $this->tmpfile = tmpfile();

}

public function write ( $data ) {

    fwrite ( $this->tmpfile, $data );

    return $this;
}

public function read () {

    fseek ( $this->tmpfile, 0);

    return fread ( $this->tmpfile, $this->size() );

}

public function uri () {

    return stream_get_meta_data ( $this->tmpfile ) ['uri'];

}

public function size () {

    return filesize ( $this->uri() );

}

public function __toString () {

    return $this->uri();
}

}
```

Пишу метод:

```
public function writeCSV ( array $data ) {

    foreach ( $data as $d) {
        fputcsv ( $this->tmpFile, array_merge( [',', $d ] ) );
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Проблема в том, что функции `fputcsv` нужен ресурс (указатель на файл), как его получить?

Comment: fopen() не подходит?

Comment: @Эдуард так зачем опять открывать открытый файл?

Comment: А вы объявляете метод `writeCSV()` в этом же классе ?

Comment: @Эдуард да в нём.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка в регистре символов свойства tmpFile. Если свойство tmpFile, то и обращаться к нему нужно tmpFile, а не tmpfile:

```
class TmpFile
{
    private $tmpFile;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tmpFile = tmpfile();
    }

    public function write( $data )
    {
        fwrite ( $this->tmpFile, $data );
        return $this;
    }

    public function read()
    {
        fseek( $this->tmpFile, 0);
        return fread( $this->tmpFile, $this->size() );
    }

    public function uri()
    {
        return stream_get_meta_data( $this->tmpFile ) ['uri'];
    }

    public function size()
    {
        return filesize( $this->uri() );
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->uri();
    }

    public function writeCSV( array $data )
    {
        foreach ($data as $d) {
            fputcsv($this->tmpFile, array_merge([',', $d ]));
        }

        return $this;
    }
}

$TmpFile = new TmpFile();

var_dump( $TmpFile->writeCSV(['что-то'])->read() );
```

Comment: Просто не заметил(